# AndroidAnnotations and Rest

Tags: rest, android-annotations

I try to follow the AndroidAnnotations [REST Documentation](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API#introduction).

But I get errors about MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter not found.

To setup AndroidAnnotations I followed the [Gradle Setup](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle)... This works fine and a small Project is working.

But as soon, I try to use MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter it stops working.

Here are my Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    compile "org.androidannotations:ormlite-api:$AAVersion"
    apt "org.androidannotations:ormlite:$AAVersion"

    compile "org.androidannotations:rest-spring-api:$AAVersion"
    apt "org.androidannotations:rest-spring:$AAVersion"

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'

}
```

What I'm missing here?

Thanks,
Urkman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to add the Spring Android REST template dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M4'
} repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}
```